# Em javaFX como capturo o evento de click no titulo da coluna para organizar os registros?

Tags: java, javafx

Tenho uma tableView e essa tem 5 colunas. 
As duas primeiras colunas estão escritas com registros que peguei do banco e as outras três são apenas botões que insiro no momento da criação da tabela.

Criei um evento para que os botões da tabela só apareçam quando eu clico no registro correspondente. ai é que esta o problema. Quando eu clico para organizar a tabela esses botões que eram para aparecer com o índice corrente não aparecem ao invés disso o evento mantém a ordem anterior, ou seja ele faz aparecer os botões da lista no índice anterior que o registro se encontrava :/.

Sei que posso resolver esse problema chamando o método responsável pela ação de aparecer e desaparecer dos botões, mas isso depois de eu organizar a coluna.

Voltando a pergunta cerne da questão.

Como eu adiciono um evento ao clicar no título de uma coluna em uma tabela no javaFX?